# SelectedItem not Passing to Property

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to assign the `.SelectedItem` to a `Property` on a secondary form that can be used by my main form, though despite a `MessageBox.Show` clearly outlining the variable has been set, my `Select Case` switches to `Case Else` and another `MessageBox.Show` shows the same variable but as `Nothing`.

(Secondary Form)

```
Public Class Setup

    Public Property HomePage As String
    Public Property WindowSize As String

    Private Sub Setup_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim SizePoss() As String = {"Desktop", "Tablet", "Mobile"}

        cmbSizeSetting.MaxDropDownItems = SizePoss.Length
        For Each column As String In SizePoss
            cmbSizeSetting.Items.Add(column)
        Next

        ' Initialize Appropriate Settings

        lblUnsaved.Hide()
        cmbSizeSetting.SelectedIndex = cmbSizeSetting.FindStringExact("Tablet")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        HomePage = txtHomepageSetting.Text
        WindowSize = cmbSizeSetting.SelectedItem
        MessageBox.Show("Size chosen was " + WindowSize + ", which is a " + TypeName(WindowSize))

        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

(Primary Form)

```
Public Class Croweb

    Private Sub btnSetup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSetup.Click
        Dim setupForm As New Setup
        setupForm.ShowDialog()

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(setupForm.HomePage) Then
            MessageBox.Show(setupForm.HomePage)
            WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri(setupForm.HomePage)
        End If

        Select Case Setup.WindowSize
            Case "Desktop"
                Me.Size = New Size(1280, 730)
            Case "Tablet"
                Me.Size = New Size(891, 564)
            Case "Phone"
                Me.Size = New Size(400, 900)
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Chosen Size is " + Setup.WindowSize + ", which is a " + TypeName(Setup.WindowSize))
        End Select

    End Sub

End Class
```

Am I passing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default form instances strike again.  No surprise there.  You start by explicitly creating an instance and displaying that:

```
Dim setupForm As New Setup
setupForm.ShowDialog()
```

Later though, you ignore that instance and use the default instance:

```
Select Case Setup.WindowSize
```

You never displayed the default instance so you never set that property in the default instance.  That line should have referred to the instance you actually did display:

```
Select Case setupForm.WindowSize
```

Comment: Jeez. Rookie mistake if I ever saw one.